# Cannot deploy/publish my WinRT App

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, publish

Nothing complicated, there is no publish in WinRT or I am missing something. I also tried deploy but I don't know where it deployed. The files in bin\Debug says only runnable in development. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, you may need some document that can guide you to publish or deploy your WinRT app, am I right?

According to [packaging UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps) , you can package your project step by step.
You can also sideload apps to your device without submitting them to the store.

More details about sideloading , you can refer to [deploy a app to another device for testing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2012/11/05/how-do-i-deploy-a-windows-8-app-to-another-device-for-testing/).

Hope it is helpful to you.